# Confusion about 'pointer-to-struct-or-union' type

Tags: c, visual-studio, linked-list

Both the snippets of code seem like they accomplish the same thing, however the first snippet compiles and executes without errors and yields expected behaviour, the second snippet does not compile.

```c
void insert_at_index(Node** head, int index, int number) {

    Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = number;
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    Node* temp = *head;
    if (index == 0) {
        new_node->next = temp;
        new_node->prev = temp->prev;
        *head = new_node;
    }
}
```

```c
void insert_at_index(Node** head, int index, int number) {

    Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = number;
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    //Node* temp = *head;
    if (index == 0) {
        new_node->next = *head;
        new_node->prev = *head->prev; //compiler error: expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
        *head = new_node;
    }
}
```

Since `**head` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct, `*head` should be a pointer to a struct right, so `*header->` should be the correct way to reference things in `Node *head` imo. But I am not sure how to fix this, also I am new to C. I am using MSVC compiler, hence the pointer casting.

Comment: Select either C++ or C as a language tag.

Comment: On a side note, don't use `malloc()` in C++, use `new` instead: `Node* new_node = new Node;`. And your function doesn't handle the case where `index > 0`

Comment: I am writing in C, and I was only testing for `index==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so `*header->` should be the correct way to reference things in `Node *head` imo.

No, and that is where your mistake is. Your thinking is on the right track, but your assumption about the syntax is wrong.

The `->` member access operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` dereference operator.  So `*head->prev` gets evaluated as `*(head->prev)`, which fails to compile since `head` is a `Node**` and so you can't apply `->` to it.  You need to use `(*head)->prev` instead to dereference `head` into a `Node*` before you can then access its members via `->`.

Comment: Had no idea about that!

Answer (score 2):

In the first code snippet you have

```
Node* temp = *head;
//...
new_node->prev = temp->prev;
```

Now make the reverse substitution for the variable `temp` in the statement

```
new_node->prev = temp->prev;
```

You will get according to the definition of the variable `temp` the following

```
new_node->prev = ( *head )->prev;
```

As you can see it is not the same as

```
new_node->prev = *head->prev;
```

in the second code snippet.

So you need at first to get an object of the type `Node *` and then to apply the operator `->`. Postfix operators like -> have higher precedence than unary operators like *. That means that the expression

```
*head->prev
```

is parsed like

```
*( head->prev )
```

You could use two postfix operators sequentially like for example

```
new_node->prev = head[0]->prev;
```

But using such an expression with pointers that do not point to arrays can confuse readers of the code.